# image lazy load not working on wordpress images

Tags: wordpress, image, lazy-loading

i can't seem for the life of me to get any image lazy loading plugins working in wordpress. I tried lazy load, wp lazy load and bj lazy load. It seems that none of the image on the site are "lazyloading". I tested this also using auditing tools (chrome audit). When the I remove the images (there are about 50 images per page), my audit performance and other scores are 99. When i load the images in (Using wordpress loop), my performance when down to 64.

I tried each of the lazy load plugins, and none of them seem to lazy load. I am testing locally but i don't think that would make a difference would it? My score never went past 64 when enabling any of those plugins.

**UPDATE**
**Chrome Dev console before activating plugin.**

[image]

**After activating bj lazy load and check to see if it loaded into the page on refresh.**

[image]

**Chrome console after activating bj lazy load, with no errors.** 
[image]

It seems to me that the page is loading fine with no errors, and that bj-lazy-load is successfully loaded on the page. I'm stumped to what else could be the issue. I have a lot of images and won't be able to go live until i can get this figured out :(.

Comment: Do you see any errors in the developer tools 'Console' tab?

Comment: I'll look when i get home definitely don't remember seeing anything but could have over looked. Will it show an error from a wordpress plugin?

Comment: It will show any JS error, among other types or issues.

Comment: I just opened the chrome console and no errors were reports, updating the original post, any other ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think since you are testing locally, the images might be lazy loading but it's so fast (because it's local server) that you don't notice it.

Here is something you can try:

1. Use BJ Lazy Load (I tested it on _s theme)
2. In plugin's settings, set 'Threshold' to 5
3. In a post, after some paragraphs, add images from an external source (not from your computer -- some links given below)
4. Then open the post in an incognito window

Lazy load should work

```
https://i.imgur.com/9wMX3fT.png
https://i.imgur.com/w7TT8Mk.png
https://i.imgur.com/3kaGaka.jpg
https://i.imgur.com/CiKYgJu.jpg
https://i.imgur.com/1oLhN39.jpg
```

Comment: Wow I never thought of that thank you! Worked like a charm, and improved my page speed by 25 points! Thank you!